# Are there better (easier) ways to get a specific domain's SID?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, active-directory

I've been assigned to modify a WinForms application to basically check that the logged on user belongs to a specific domain.
This is what I've come up with so far:

```
byte[] domainSid;

var directoryContext =
    new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "domain.se");

using (var domain = Domain.GetDomain(directoryContext))
using (var directoryEntry = domain.GetDirectoryEntry())
    domainSid = (byte[])directoryEntry.Properties["objectSid"].Value;

var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(domainSid, 0);
bool validUser = UserPrincipal.Current.Sid.IsEqualDomainSid(sid);
```

Is there a better/easier way to do this?
To me it seems like the domainSid would be accessible in some way using the PrincipalContext or some other class in System.Security.Principal.

I've considered using a hardcoded SID-string, but I don't know how "correct" that would be.

Comment: Note that in localized versions of Windows the administrator's name can be different.
For example, in Russian Windows there is no "administrator" user, but "Администратор" instead, so hard-coding administrator's name is not a very good idea.

Comment: FYI: For the current user's domain you can use: `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.AccountDomainSid`

Comment: Note: for those using PowerShell: `(Get-AdDomain -Identity 'myDomain').DomainSID` works.  That cmdlet is part of the `ActiveDirectory` module.  The `Get-AdDomain` cmdlet returns an object of type `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADDomain`.  Sadly that class doesn't have any special .net options for resolving a name to the SID as hoped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing looks like the best option to me. Hardcoding strings is definetely not a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Each domain has a build in account **domainName\administrator**, so you can create an account with this name, translate it to the SecurityIdentifier and read the AccountDomainSid property.

An example of this way is:

```
public static class SecurityEx
{
    public static SecurityIdentifier DomainSId
    {
        get
        {               
            var administratorAcount = new NTAccount(GetDomainName(), "administrator");
            var administratorSId = (SecurityIdentifier) administratorAcount.Translate(typeof (SecurityIdentifier));
            return administratorSId.AccountDomainSid;
        }
    }

    internal static string GetDomainName()
    {
        //could be other way to get the domain name through Environment.UserDomainName etc...
        return IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
    }
}
```

Also you can find other solutions to achieve the same result via WMI or Lsa. This one seems the most elegant way for me.

Comment: Not all the domains have "administrator" account.  The default "Administrator" can be renamed to something else by Group Policy.  Actually, it's recommended to rename it for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different approach to the accepted answer:

### C#

```
using System.Security.Principal; 
using System.DirectoryServices;  

//...

void Main()
{
    var sidHelp = new SecurityIdentifierHelper();
    Console.WriteLine(sidHelp.GetDomainSecurityIdentifier("MyDomain"));
}

//...

public class SecurityIdentifierHelper
{
    const int OffsetBinaryFormStartingIndex = 0; // just to avoid magic numbers; though this is still a bit magic.  Documentation says "The byte offset to use as the starting index in binaryForm", whatever that means.
                                                 // https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/principal/sid.cs,d06a8d5ee0c7a26d,references
                                                 // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Principal_SecurityIdentifier__ctor_System_Byte___System_Int32_
    public SecurityIdentifier GetDomainSecurityIdentifier(string domain)
    {
        var ldapPath = $"LDAP://{domain}";
        var domainAdsi = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath);
        var domainSidByteArray = (byte[])domainAdsi.Properties["objectSid"].Value;
        return new SecurityIdentifier(domainSidByteArray, OffsetBinaryFormStartingIndex);
    }
}
```

### C# One Liner

```
Console.WriteLine(new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(((byte[])new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://MyDomain").Properties["objectSid"].Value), 0));
```

### PowerShell:

```
[string]$myDomain = 'MyDomain' # or 'MyDomain.example.com'
[string]$ldapPath = 'LDAP://{0}' -f $MyDomain
[adsi]$domainAdsi = [adsi]$ldapPath
[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($domainAdsi.Value, 0)
```

### PowerShell 1 Liner:

```
[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new(([ADSI]('LDAP://MyDomain')).Value, 0)
```

Comment: `([ADSI]('LDAP://MyDomain)).Value` wasn't working for me; instead, try `([ADSI]('LDAP://MyDomain)).objectSid.Value` to get the bytes

Comment: ...and the *OffsetBinaryFromStartingIndex* is the position in the given byte array from which to start reading the SID -- it is `0` if the byte array *is* (or *starts with*) the SID, but the constructor also allows for passing a byte array that *contains* the SID, if you know where it *starts*

Answer (score 0):

To get the sid of domain just this simple query is needed:

```
public static SecurityIdentifier GetDomainSid(string domainName)
{
    byte[] domainSidBytes = ((byte[])new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{ domainName }").Properties["objectSid"].Value);
    SecurityIdentifier sid = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(domainSidBytes, 0);
    return sid;
}
```

Caution: this method throws exceptions when the domain name cannot be resolved or the user has no permissions to query Active Directory.